# Adding php variable to <a href name part

Tags: variables, href

Here is my code there is plenty more but these work independently

```
echo $row['Queue'];
echo "<a href=\"modifyp.php?id=" . $row['id1'] . "\">Modify</a>";
```

what I want to do is this

```
echo "<a href=\"modifyp.php?id=" . $row['id1'] . "\">$row['Queue']</a>";
```

this doesn't work and gives a syntax error. any tips on how to get this to work?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be:

```
echo "<a href=\"modifyp.php?id=" . $row['id1'] . "\">" . $row['Queue'] . "</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<a href=\"modifyp.php?id=" . $row['id1'] . "\">".$row['Queue']."</a>";
```